# Go Unmarshal JSON, but unmarshal nested structure as a string

Tags: json, go

Given the following JSON object:

```
{
"a": 1,
"b": [1,2,3,4]
}
```

And the following `type`:

```
type Thing struct {
  A Int `json:"a"`
  B string `json:"b"
}
```

I would like the Array "b" to stay as a JSON string when marshalled into go.

I currently get the following error:

`panic: json: cannot unmarshal array into Go struct field Thing.b of type string`

Comment: That's not how JSON does or should work. If you want a string you should really have a string in the JSON.

Comment: Set that field as a [`json.RawMessage`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#RawMessage).  It'll be stored as is, without interpretation (ie. as `"[1,2,3,4]"`), as a slice of bytes, which can be converted to a string easily enough.  If you need a string directly, you'll have to implement the [json.Unmarshaler interface](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshaler) on your type and do the conversion yourself.

Comment: @Kaedys that works! Would you mind leaving that as the answer below so that you can claim it?

Comment: @Adrian haha that's pretty funny.

Comment: @Breedly, I think @Adrian is being serious, it should be a string if you want a string, i.e.: `{"a":1, "b":"[1,2,3,4]"}` is what the JSON should be if you want a string, that is JSON, out of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the field as a [`json.RawMessage`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#RawMessage). It'll be stored as is, without interpretation (ie. as `"[1,2,3,4]"`), as a slice of bytes, which can be converted to a string easily enough.

If you need a string directly, you'll have to implement the [json.Unmarshaler interface](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshaler) on your type and do the conversion yourself.